# how to transfer files from windows 8.1 to ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8, connection

I have all my files on my brother's PC and now I want to copy them to mine.

Installing a programme didn't help me because it's about 200 GB and takes a long time and sometimes my connection failed.

How can I connect my laptop to my brother's PC with a cable?

Comment: it's a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Set the Windows PC to export the target directories with SMB (samba) and then connect to your router with a cable. We can't help with the details though, since that involves setting up file sharing on Windows. I suggest you delete this and ask on [su] instead.

Comment: **:D** One year and a half later you've accepted!  Better late then never!  **;-)** إن شاء الله

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest (and fastest) way is to buy a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable), plug it into both machines and install [NitroShare](http://nitroshare.net/downloads/) on both the Windows and Ubuntu System.

On the Windows PC, right-click the NitroShare icon, choose <kbd>Send Directory</kbd> and send the directory with your files over to the Ubuntu System...

### Done!

P.S. If you're short on cash, don't buy the cross-cable and use WiFi (but be patient then...)